# Turn off Android storage encryption

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm developing an app using .NET MAUI and I'm storing data using `ISecureStorage`. On Android this is hurting the performance of the app. I've read that the encryption Android is doing is quite slow compared to iOS where it's pretty much instant and none of the data is sensitive in any way so the encryption is really not needed. I understand from the name `ISecureStorage` that it's supposed to be secure but there's no other alternative in MAUI as far as I'm aware. So is there any way of disabling the encryption on Android?

Comment: What sort of app are you making where the performance of _storage_ is so important as a function of the _size of the data you wish to store?_  Unless your app is utilising storage _constantly_ (which would be unfortunate for the battery) or you are storing vast amounts of data, any storage API shouldn't be a problem for a typical app's data size requirements.

Comment: @MickyD I have about 600+ different types of properties a user can select as a favorite (A user is limited to 50). Everytime the app starts I loop through all the properties (600+) and check if they exist in the storage (`storage.GetAsync()`) in order to cache the favorites throughout the lifetime of the current session. On Android this process takes up to 1-2 minute(s). On iOS, as I stated in the post, this process is instant (~10ms).

Comment: 600+ I/o operations on startup does not sound like a good design

Comment: @Jason Hmm I understand. Do you have any suggestions? I've thought about implementing SQLite, however, I would like to avoid it if possible but if there are no viable solutions to this I guess I don't really have any choice.

Comment: You haven’t provided any detail about what you’re doing so it’s impossible to offer any suggestions

Comment: Serialize to json and store the resulting string in a file.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yeah that's what I ended up doing. Thanks though!